# Ranking SQL Server Query results

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Is there a way in SQL Server to rank rows based on the values in the `WHERE` clause?

For instance:

```
SELECT *
FROM Foo
WHERE 
  Bar1 = true AND
  Bar2 = true OR
  Bar3 = false
```

The best result in this case would be a row where Bar1 = true, Bar2 = true and Bar3 = false. A row where Bar1 = true, Bar2 = true and Bar3 = true would score lower because Bar3 is different.

To make it even more complicated. The WHERE clause is dynamic, I don't know exactly which columns will appear in the query. So the next query could be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Foo
WHERE 
  Bar1 = false OR
  Bar3 = true OR
  Bar4 = True
```

How can I apply ranking to those queries?

Can this be done within the query or is it better to do this in C#?

Comment: You appy a `WHERE`, does that mean you want to exclude rows? If so, what rows do you want to keep and what are the columns you want to group by? Can you provide sample data and a desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the results by the number of `where` clauses that match:

```
order by ((case when Bar1 = true AND Bar2 = true then 1 else end) +
          (case when Bar3 = false then 1 else 0 end)
         ) desc
```

You could also add this to a field in the `select`.  If you are dynamically creating the `where`, you would have to do the same thing for the `order by` (or `select` variable).

I would advise you to do this in the database, because replicating the logic between SQL and C# seems like a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE 
     AS (SELECT T.*, 
                RN = ROW_NUMBER() 
                       OVER ( 
                         ORDER BY BAR1 ASC, BAR2 ASC, BAR3 DESC) 
         FROM   DBO.TABLENAME T) 
SELECT * 
FROM   CTE 
ORDER  BY RN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give each clause a score of 1 if it is satisfied and 0 if it is not satisfied. And then you can order by the sum of scores.

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Foo
ORDER BY cast((Bar1 = true) as int)
       + cast((Bar2 = true OR Bar3 = false) as int)
DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what do you mean by `true` in SQL Server. If you Bars are bit columns, you can rank like this:

```
select *
from Foo
order by
    case
       when Bar1 = 1 and Bar2 = 1 and Bar3 = 0 then 0
       else 1
    end asc
```

if it's strings:

```
select *
from Foo
order by
    case
       when Bar1 = 'true' and Bar2 = 'true' and Bar3 = 'false' then 0
       else 1
    end asc
```